# DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn does not display CheckBoxCell for all rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have been trying for few hours to add a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn to an existing DataGridView with the designer and through code. The CheckBoxCell is not displaying the square (or state) on the UI. However, when I tried some code that I found (and forgot to change the index), I got it working and displaying normally.

So I am wondering why you cannot use a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn at the last index of the DataGridView.Columns ?

---

To be more explicit:

Why does this work

```
MyDataGridView.Columns.Insert(0, myCheckBoxColumn);
```

When this does not work

```
MyDataGridView.Columns.Insert(7, myCheckBoxColumn);
```

**Note: The myCheckBoxColumn variable did not change between the two lines. It is exactly the same and is irrelevant to the actual problem.**

---

Edit:

Using the Add method like bellow does not solve the problem.

```
MyDataGridView.Columns.Add(myCheckBoxColumn);
```

---

Resolved:

My problem was related to the handling of the CellPainting event of the DataGridView. At the end of the function, the property Handled of the DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs was set to true. This was causing the DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn to not display properly.

Comment: When you downvote at least explain why...

Comment: I guess the downvotes were because of the vagueness of the title.

Comment: Is it more clear this way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a column to the right, use the Add method of DataGridViewColumnCollection instead:

```
MyDataGridView.Columns.Add(myCheckBoxColumn);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried it and I have the same behavior as described. The checkbox cell does not display the square and I cannot interact with it. The only thing I changed was to replace the insert call for the add call.

Comment: Do you have any custom painting code on the grid ?

Comment: You actually help me figured it out. In the painting event, the DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs had the property Hanled set to true at the end. That cause my problem. I will update my post to include it in case it can help others and I will mark the post answered and your post as the answer. Thank you !

Comment: Awesome...glad to help